# how can I install venv in windows 10

Tags: python, python-venv

my goal is to install python 3.9 on venv

the process that I did :

```
mkdir nice
cd nice
python3 -m venv
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

when i tried to run :

```
python3.9 -m venv env
```

i got the error:

```
'python3.9' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> i got the error:
>
> ```
> 'python3.9' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

You could try `where python` to find your Python installation on Windows. If that fails, you can look around the location of `where pip`, since that is installed.

`python --version` will show you the installed version of Python.

You can then create you venv like this:

```
python -m venv venv
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `python3.9` as the main argument of your command. The correct way to create your environnement using Python 3.9 is : `python -m virtualenv venv -p python3.9`. If this fails, replace python3.9 with the full path to python 3.9 executable.